# Pandas dataframe average for each row conditional on dates

Tags: python, pandas, date, conditional-statements, mean

In a pandas dataframe with project data (input table), I am trying to calculate the historic mean of 'Success' for each row. The conditions are:

1. Only consider projects with the same 'Customer" as in calculated row
2. Only consider projects with an 'End Date' before the 'Start Date' of the project in calculated row
3. If there was no project that ended already with a particular customer, a blank should be returned

Any help is very appreciated as i do not know where to start with this. Thanks.

Input table

```
Project ID    Start Date    End Date    Success Customer Name
8403986       3/13/2015     9/9/2015    0.396   ENGINEERING INC
92083597      6/20/2016     12/24/2016  0.3     ENGINEERING INC
13979865      3/18/2019     5/5/2019    0.2004  ENGINEERING INC
93106418      1/22/2017     11/6/2017   0.374   MANAGEMENT CORP
3658851       8/5/2018      12/17/2018  0.5002  SERVICES INC
116547576     10/31/2015    12/30/2015  0.478   MANAGEMENT CORP
4164070       10/2/2018     10/12/2018  0.5     ENGINEERING INC
49701600      12/23/2017    10/1/2018   0.226   MANAGEMENT CORP
6235002       9/27/2016     4/25/2017   0.542   MANAGEMENT CORP
54113980      10/27/2015    1/2/2016    0.344   ENGINEERING INC
104596325     7/3/2015      2/17/2016   0.455   MANAGEMENT CORP 
69580391      8/9/2016      1/10/2017   0.39    ENGINEERING INC
111382294     1/13/2017     10/18/2017  0.299   SERVICES INC
7904360       12/12/2015    3/16/2016   0.281   MANAGEMENT CORP
117003225     5/5/2017      5/12/2017   0.2868  SERVICES INC
99819795      10/9/2015     1/14/2016   0.356   ENGINEERING INC
122919691     1/16/2016     10/24/2016  0.474   SERVICES INC
```

Output table

```
Project ID    Start Date    End Date    Success Customer Name    Historic Success
8403986       3/13/2015     9/9/2015    0.396   ENGINEERING INC  
92083597      6/20/2016     12/24/2016  0.3     ENGINEERING INC  0.365
13979865      3/18/2019     5/5/2019    0.2004  ENGINEERING INC  0.381
93106418      1/22/2017     11/6/2017   0.374   MANAGEMENT CORP  0.405
3658851       8/5/2018      12/17/2018  0.5002  SERVICES INC     0.353
116547576     10/31/2015    12/30/2015  0.478   MANAGEMENT CORP  
4164070       10/2/2018     10/12/2018  0.5     ENGINEERING INC  0.357
49701600      12/23/2017    10/1/2018   0.226   MANAGEMENT CORP  0.439
6235002       9/27/2016     4/25/2017   0.542   MANAGEMENT CORP  0.405
54113980      10/27/2015    1/2/2016    0.344   ENGINEERING INC  0.396
104596325     7/3/2015      2/17/2016   0.455   MANAGEMENT CORP  
69580391      8/9/2016      1/10/2017   0.39    ENGINEERING INC  0.365
111382294     1/13/2017     10/18/2017  0.299   SERVICES INC     0.474
7904360       12/12/2015    3/16/2016   0.281   MANAGEMENT CORP  
117003225     5/5/2017      5/12/2017   0.2868  SERVICES INC     0.474
99819795      10/9/2015     1/14/2016   0.356   ENGINEERING INC  0.396
122919691     1/16/2016     10/24/2016  0.474   SERVICES INC
```

**e.g. project '92083597' with 'Engineering INC' with 'Start Date'=6/20/2016**

Condition 1: Only rows with 'Customer' = Engineering INC are considered

```
Project ID    Start Date    End Date    Success Customer Name    
8403986       3/13/2015     9/9/2015    0.396   ENGINEERING INC  
92083597      6/20/2016     12/24/2016  0.3     ENGINEERING INC  
13979865      3/18/2019     5/5/2019    0.2004  ENGINEERING INC  
4164070       10/2/2018     10/12/2018  0.5     ENGINEERING INC  
54113980      10/27/2015    1/2/2016    0.344   ENGINEERING INC  
69580391      8/9/2016      1/10/2017   0.39    ENGINEERING INC  
99819795      10/9/2015     1/14/2016   0.356   ENGINEERING INC
```

Condition 2: Only rows with 'End Date' before 6/20/2016 are considered

```
Project ID    Start Date    End Date    Success Customer Name    
8403986       3/13/2015     9/9/2015    0.396   ENGINEERING INC  
54113980      10/27/2015    1/2/2016    0.344   ENGINEERING INC  
99819795      10/9/2015     1/14/2016   0.356   ENGINEERING INC
```

The mean from the remaining three rows (0.369+0.344+0.356)/ 3 is **0.365**.
This will be returned and is the "Historic Success" for row project '92083597'.
If no projects are left after first or second condition blank is returned.

Comment: You should post your data sample as text, not as images. People cannot grab numbers from an image to test an answer.

Comment: @Valentino ,questions has been edited, sorry for that, I am new and still learning

Comment: Yeah, that's fine. But can you better explain how do you calculate the Historic Success? I cannot follow the logic.

Comment: @Valentino, added example to hopefully make it clearer

Answer (score 2):

You should break this problem up into multiple sub-problems if you really want to learn how to solve it. It will help you to become a great programmer and also allow you to take bits and pieces of various stack overflow answers. In addition, you should also avoid spaces in column names

Here's the way I would do it but there could be faster ways to do this

First you should sort the dataframe by date, make sure that you're data is formatted correctly. You can use the code below to help ensure that it sorts correctly. It first makes sure the column is in the correct format, and then sorts based on Customer_Name to group them together and then sorts based on dates to organize projects

```
df['End_Date'] =pd.to_datetime(df["End_Date"])
df = df.sort_values(["Customer_Name", "End_Date"])
```

Then calculate an average of each company based on the previous success rate. For this you have to calculate a running average in pandas. This can be done by using a loop, but there is generally a faster way to do this in Pandas.

```
df.groupby("Customer_Name").Success.expanding().mean()
```

This will generate the running mean of each Customer_Name inorder of date. The complete code is here below. You should try to look at each of the sub-problems I've created and see if you can make the solutions better or perhaps add more sub-problems that you might need.

```
df['End_Date'] =pd.to_datetime(df["End_Date"])
df = df.sort_values(["Customer_Name", "End_Date"])
df["Historic_Success"] = df.groupby("Customer_Name")
                       .Success
                       .expanding()
                       .mean()
                       .values
```

Hope that answers your question. If you would like to sort the dataframe back into the format it was in you can sort by index as I haven't reindexed the dataframe in my code.

Edit: 
To avoid the first success rate being present in the historical success you can add an input of "2" to the expanding function.

```
df["Historic_Success"] = df.groupby("Customer_Name")
                       .Success
                       .expanding(2)
                       .mean()
                       .values
```

But this would still include the success rate of the current project in the mean. This would mean that the historical success rate of project 1 will be the mean of project 1's and project 2's success rate.

To avoid this the best way to avoid that you should use the code below.

```
df["Historic_Success"] = df.groupby("Customer_Name").Success.shift(1)
df.Historic_Success = df.groupby("Customer_Name")
                       .Historic_Success
                       .expanding()
                       .mean()
                       .values
```

Here after you organize the data into customer names and dates, you shift the success data down by 1. Then you run the same line of code on the shifted data.

Comment: Thank you Siddarth, this brings me closer to a solutions.
The remaining challenge is that this code will also take the 'Success' of the row on which the calculation is done. 
i.e. Project 8403986 will result in a "Historic_Success" of 0.396 but there was not project with that customer before.

Comment: Hey Matt, I've edited the answer, hope that clears up any questions you have. You would be interested in the final code sequence to get the output you would want.